# How To get Value From Bash Script ( linux )

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read in the value from a bash script and I'm not sure why the value for `x` is not getting set.

```
import os

speed = "cat /sys/class/net/enxf01e3414460e/speed"
x=os.popen(speed)
y=10000

print(x.read())

if x < y:
    print ("xxx")
else:
    print ("success")
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a more pythonic way.

Could something like the following work instead?

```
import os

y=10000

with open('/sys/class/net/enxf01e3414460e/speed') as f:
    x = int(next(f)) # int cast is probably wrong. Not sure what type of data to expect here

if x < y:
    print ("xxx")
else:
    print ("succsess")
```